# Default "Please Select" value using echo

Tags: php, html, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to add "Please select" before my values.

```
<?php
      include "dbconnect.php";
      $resultSet = $con->query("SELECT eventDuration, durationName FROM tbl_duration");
      ?>
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="eventDuration">Duration:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select name="eventDuration">
      <?php
         while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
         {
            $durationName = $rows['durationName'];
         echo "<option value='0'>Please select...</option>";
            echo "<option value='$durationName'>$durationName</option>";
         }
         ?>
      </select>
   </div>
```

I tried the code above but the results are repetitive as you can see below. How can I make it so it does not repeat itself?

```
Please select
1 Day
Please select
2 Days
Please select
3 Days
```

Comment: You can move `echo "<option value='0'>Please select...</option>";` out of the loop

Comment: Does <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
  <?php
    foreach($resultSet as $eventDuration) { ?>
      <option value="<?= $eventDuration['durationName'] ?>"><?= $eventDuration['durationName'] ?></option>
  <?php
    } ?> work as well?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can take the default `<option>` out of the loop.

```
<?php
include "dbconnect.php";
$resultSet = $con->query("SELECT eventDuration, durationName FROM tbl_duration");
?>
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="eventDuration">Duration:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select name="eventDuration">
        <option value='0'>Please select...</option>
        <?php foreach ($resultSet as $row): ?>
        <option value='<?=htmlspecialchars($row['durationName']) ?>'><?=htmlspecialchars($row['durationName']) ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```